Postgres SQL state: 23502 on upddate in the column integer, constraint not null, with valid value of 0 or 1
I have 2 postgres tables:

tb_provaDoCandidato and
tb_questoesProvaDoCandidato in practice a sub-set of the first one.

Both table have a column named "respostaCandidato" type integer with NOT NULL constraint.
When a try to process the query below :
UPDATE public."tb_provaDoCandidato" pc
        SET "respostaCandidato" = (SELECT qp."respostaCandidato" FROM public."tb_questoesProvaDoCandidato" qp
        WHERE   pc."numeroDaProva" = qp."numeroDaProva" 
        AND     pc."idQuestao" = qp."idQuestao"
        AND     pc."idAlternativa" = qp."respostaIdAlternativa")

occurs the error message below :
ERROR:  null value in column "respostaCandidato" violates not-null
constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, 100, 1, 27, 77668219234,
B, 0, 4, 186, 40354463, 41350981, null, 2024-03-31 22:33:16, null, 14,

The column indicated as "null" (first one after the value 41350981) in fact is not null. See the line below extract from a query :
3   100 1   27  77668219234 "B" 0   4   186 40354463    41350981    0

Also in the table tb_questoesProvaDoCandidato the column "respostaCandidato" has an integer, constraint not null, with the value 0 or 1.
At least 2 things intrigate me :

days ago this update had being  works well, Could be any feature in the configuration of PgAdmin?;
when I remove the constraint in the both tables, when the value of "respostaCandidato" in tb_questoesProvaDoCandidato  is 0 (zeroes), the update put null in the "respostaCandidato" at tb_provaDoCandidato

What´s happening ? How to solve that problem ?
I already recreate both tables (with drop cascade) and nothing worked.


From UPDATE: sub-SELECT ...   if it yields no rows, NULL values are assigned to the target columns..  Are you sure there is a matching row for "tb_questoesProvaDoCandidato" for the WHERE and AND filters given? 2) To your question text add, as text, the table definitions.


Also what is the purpose of ... SET "respostaCandidato" = (SELECT qp."respostaCandidato" ...? In other words how do you know that you are updating the correct "respostaCandidato"?

In the update statement the column "respostaCandidato" near at SET command is the column to being update in the table tb_provaDoCandidato.  Adding the alias name "pc" in this col name, the query turn error. As I said if the constraint is removed null is putted in the column when 0 and 1 otherwise.


You have not  added the table definitions to your question. 2) Per the docs UPDATE: Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, UPDATE table_name SET table_name.col = 1 is invalid. 3) Again it is most likely NULL because the conditions of the sub-select are not finding any rows that match so  qp."respostaCandidato" is set to NULL per my previous comment. 4) There is no WHERE on the outer UPDATE query so you are setting "respostaCandidato" to that value for every row.


CREATE TABLE public."tb_questoesProvaDoCandidato"
(
............
"idQuestao" bigint NOT NULL,
"respostaCandidato" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"respostaIdAlternativa" bigint,

CONSTRAINT "tb_questoesProvaDoCandidato_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("numeroDaProva", "idProcesso", "numInscricaoCandidato", "idQuestao"),
CONSTRAINT "tb_questoesProvaDoCandidato_uk" UNIQUE (id)


Per previous requests add to question text as properly formatted text.

CREATE TABLE public."tb_provaDoCandidato"
(
"idQuestao" bigint NOT NULL,
"idAlternativa" bigint,
"respostaCandidato" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

"respostaCertaOuErrada" character(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
CONSTRAINT "tb_provaDoCandidato_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("idCandidato", id),
CONSTRAINT "tb_provaDoCandidato_uk" UNIQUE (id)


I think, you update all rows of main table tb_provaDoCandidato. A you shure, that subquery to sub-set table returns value or returns not null  value for all rows?

Try add condition WHERE EXISTS(SELECT qp."respostaCandidato" FROM public."tb_questoesProvaDoCandidato" qp WHERE pc."numeroDaProva" = qp."numeroDaProva" AND pc."idQuestao" = qp."idQuestao" AND pc."idAlternativa" = qp."respostaIdAlternativa")

Not an answer, a long comment explaining what I was trying to get at in my question comments.
This
UPDATE public."tb_provaDoCandidato" pc
        SET "respostaCandidato" = (SELECT qp."respostaCandidato" FROM public."tb_questoesProvaDoCandidato" qp
        WHERE   pc."numeroDaProva" = qp."numeroDaProva" 
        AND     pc."idQuestao" = qp."idQuestao"
        AND     pc."idAlternativa" = qp."respostaIdAlternativa")

is doing an UPDATE on all the rows in tb_provaDoCandidato as there is no WHERE clause for the UPDATE statement itself. This means this:
SELECT qp."respostaCandidato" FROM public."tb_questoesProvaDoCandidato" qp
        WHERE   pc."numeroDaProva" = qp."numeroDaProva" 
        AND     pc."idQuestao" = qp."idQuestao"
        AND     pc."idAlternativa" = qp."respostaIdAlternativa"

is being run for each row with new values for the pc.* fields. At some point in the process this:
 WHERE   pc."numeroDaProva" = qp."numeroDaProva" 
        AND     pc."idQuestao" = qp."idQuestao"
        AND     pc."idAlternativa" = qp."respostaIdAlternativa"

is not finding a matching row in tb_questoesProvaDoCandidato. In that case the value for respostaCandidato is set to NULL and you get your error. It probably worked before because there where matching rows for every row in tb_provaDoCandidato. At some point you added data to tb_provaDoCandidato that does not have a corresponding row in respostaCandidato.
I'm thinking there is a better way to do this, though how to get there is going to depend on an explanation from you as to what you are trying to achieve with this UPDATE? My best guess is you are trying to do the same thing as what a FOREIGN KEY  relationship would provide.

Adrian, tks for your comment. In fact you explain with a focus and detail about how sql really works that I didn't know.  Tks.
